# Broken SSL on dailymotion oembed

Tags: ssl, oembed, dailymotion-api

I'm currently implementing dailymotion but I have noticed probably a bug on dailymotion. Modern Browsers impose that all iframe srcs should be SSL as well when you have a secured connection. Otherwise the iframe won't load.

When you send an URL the following url to 
https://www.dailymotion.com/services/oembed?url=https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x16h0i1_aveugle-de-11-ans-chante-wrecking-ball-miley-cyrus_news

you receive back:

```
{
    "type":"video",
    "version":"1.0",
    "provider_name":"Dailymotion",
    "provider_url":"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com",
    "title":"Aveugle de 11 ans chante Wrecking Ball - Miley Cyrus",
    "author_name":"Spi0n",
    "author_url":"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/Spi0n",
    "width":480,
    "height":326,
    "html":"<iframe src=\"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/embed\/video\/x16h0i1\" width=\"480\" height=\"326\" frameborder=\"0\"><\/iframe>",
    "thumbnail_url":"https:\/\/s2-ssl.dmcdn.net\/Cu30E\/x240-c-G.jpg",
    "thumbnail_width":353,
    "thumbnail_height":240
}
```

the SSL is broken. Is there a way to fix it?

Thx
Olivier

Comment: what do you mean by "the ssl is broken" ? is your problem that you get "html":"</iframe>" instead of the right iframe data, or is it that you get http instead of https ?

Comment: A fix is on the way, hang on!

Answer (score 0):

We just pushed a fix on our side, it should now fully serve HTTPS URLs when on the HTTPS endpoint. Thank you for reporting this issue.